# What does the word "but" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

I was watching this motivational video, with excerpts from a Podcast Joe Rogan Experience, and Kevin Hart is speaking about how bad things happen to you, but they will eventually pass. He used a phrase with the word "but" that I didn't understand. He says:

"There's a payoff for bad eventually"
"It can't be bad **but for so long**

What does the word "but" mean here?

Is it an intensive like in this TFD def?
2. Used as an intensive: Get out of here but fast!

Edit: this is the part when he says it  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLDBDpfPWjE&ab_channel=BetterSelf

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. Maybe it would with more context.

Comment: When people talk they say all kinds of odd things in connected speech. Just disregard it. He means: except for so long. i.e. some period of time. The word but can mean except.

Comment: It *can* be bad but *not* for so long!

Comment: This seems to be [the bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLDBDpfPWjE&ab_channel=BetterSelf).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, That's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> [**but**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Adverb), adverb (*not comparable*)
>
> 1. (*chiefly literary or poetic*) Merely, only, just, no more than
>    Synonyms: see [Thesaurus:merely](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:merely)
>    *Christmas comes **but** once a year.*

So "It **can't** [can not] be bad **but** for so long" means "It **can** be bad **only** for so long." In other words, the length of time for which "it" will be bad is limited; eventually things will be better.

Note that the example sentence is not, strictly speaking, an example of good usage because it contains a double negative. This is common in informal speech.

Comment: I thought about it like this: *It can't be bad but (=except) for so (=this [limited and defined]) long* but your answer is better!

Comment: That's a good interpretation as well!

Comment: randomhead@ Kevin@ How about the suggestion I provided at the end of the post? Can it be an intensive? Then the sentence would have the meaning of " It can't be bad **but (meaning: for very)**long"